# How to convert a date in own format in Android

Tags: java, android, date, format

In my JSON response i am getting date like this `[1987,8,22]`, but I have to display the date like `22-08-1987`. Can anyone tell me how to convert this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got the dateString in from json??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this::

```
String date = "1987,8,22";

String[] part = date.split(",");

date = part[2]+"-"+part[1]+"-"+part[0];
```

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`org.json`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) package to parse the JSON into a `JSONArray` (if your haven't already done so). Then you can [instantiate a `GregorianCalendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) using the three elements of the array accessible through `JSONArray.getInt`. This date then can be formatted as any other Java date object.

Comment: Could you please give me some clarification. I didn't get you. Please give some sample. I am getting jsondate like string date = jsonObject.getstring("dateOfBirth");

Comment: Please post some code you've written by editing your question and point out where it doesn't work like you'd want it to.

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

String date = jsonObject.getString("dateOfBirth");

I am getting response like this

{ "username":"tst","password":"123456",
"dateOfBirth":[1987,8,22],"gender":"M","height":64.0,"weight":62.0 }

Now I ahve to show this date in a edit text like 22-08-1987.

How can i do this?

Comment: Instead of `getString`, use `jsonObject.getJSONArray("dateOfBirth")` and then you can access the three parts (year, month, day) using the `getInt` method of the `JSONArray` object. Use those to construct a `GregorianCalendar` (see link in the answer above) and you can format that using `DateFormat`: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html